# how to add table in ggplot grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to summary table next to the scatterplot in the final figure. The summary table should come next to the plot. Here is the sample code.

How can we do that?

Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

# data
x <- runif(10000)
y <- runif(10000)
z <- c(rep(0, 5000), rep(1, 5000))

tbl <- tibble(x, y, z)

# plot
scatterplot <- ggplot(tbl,
                      aes(x = x,
                          y = y)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7,
             size = 2) +
  facet_grid(. ~ z) + 
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  ggtitle("Scatter plot")

# add summary table
summary_tbl <- tbl %>%
  group_by(z) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            x_mean = mean(x),
            y_mean = mean(y))


# TASK
# to create a final plot with scatterplot and summary table in single row grid
plot_grid(scatterplot, summary_tbl,
          nol = 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `patchwork`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)
library(patchwork)
# data
x <- runif(10000)
y <- runif(10000)
z <- c(rep(0, 5000), rep(1, 5000))

tbl <- tibble(x, y, z)

# plot
scatterplot <- ggplot(tbl,
                      aes(x = x,
                          y = y)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7,
             size = 2) +
  facet_grid(. ~ z) + 
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1) +
  ggtitle("Scatter plot")

# add summary table
summary_tbl <- tbl %>%
  group_by(z) %>%
  summarise(count = n(),
            x_mean = mean(x),
            y_mean = mean(y))


# TASK
G <- scatterplot + gridExtra::tableGrob(summary_tbl)
```

Output:

[image]

You can wrap your table using `gridExtra::tableGrob()`

Try this for colors and order:

```
# TASK 2
my_table_theme <- gridExtra::ttheme_default(core=list(bg_params = list(fill = 'white', col=NA)))
#Plot
G <- scatterplot / gridExtra::tableGrob(summary_tbl,
                                        rows = NULL,theme=my_table_theme)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @r2evans For sure your answer must be 100/100 more elaborated :)

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to format the table 1. in theme-bw() and 2. remove no. from leftside.

Comment: and how to position it, lets say I want to place the table below the figure. I thought of creating another plot object for table and then use cowplot to arrange as desired

Comment: @SiD I have added an update, let me know if that works for you!